# Swift 3 - Detecting new lines in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I'm trying to count (real-time) new lines on UITextView, I found the below method that works well but I actually need to add more features but I don't know how to do.

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let pos = textView.endOfDocument
    let currentRect = textView.caretRect(for: pos)
    if previousRect != CGRect.zero {
        if currentRect.origin.y > previousRect.origin.y {
            //increase the counter
            counter += 1
        }
    }
    previousRect = currentRect
}
```

Ok so, the code works fine, but I need to:

1. decrease the counter `counter -= 1` when the user delete a line
2. actually this code increase the counter when new line is detected, instead I need to increase the counter when the return button on the keyboard is pressed giving the user the possibility to exceed the frame width of the text view without increase the counter

I don't know how to do that, do you have any suggestions?

**EDIT (Visual Example)**

[image]

the output here is 4

Comment: Could you rephrase: ' actually this code increase the counter when new line is detected, instead I need to increase the counter when the return button on the keyboard is pressed giving the user the possibility to exceed the frame width of the text view without increase the counter ' U want the user to be able to add new lines without it increasing the counter?

Comment: @Emptyless No, this code increase the counter when the origin (y) of the current rect is greater than the origin of the previous rect (y) this means that if the user type a long phrase that exceeds the textView width the counter is incremented by one because a new line is found. Instead I need to increase the counter when the user press the return key to go on a new line. Please see the EDIT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself, I will post the code below if someone need it (check comments in the code):

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let pos = textView.endOfDocument
    let currentRect = textView.caretRect(for: pos)
    if previousRect != CGRect.zero {
        if currentRect.origin.y > previousRect.origin.y {
            // Array of Strings
            var currentLines = textView.text.components(separatedBy: "\n")
            // Remove Blank Strings
            currentLines = currentLines.filter{ $0 != "" }
            //increase the counter counting how many items inside the array
            counter = currentLines.count
        }
    }
    previousRect = currentRect
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could listen to every individual character change and just check if it's the new line or not with this delegate function https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/1618630-textview